It's there a way to use YouTube videos as backgrounds that didn't use jQuery?
I'm using Splide to create a slider and the video extension to add videos to the slides however, if I use it with a YouTube video it runs the video in its native ratio with an the usual YouTube branding and controls - not as a background video as I want.
The site I am rebuilding uses Slick slider (not been updated in 7 years) and leverages this jQuery plugin (https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer) to create what I need.
My site is React/Next and most solutions that work here are for local videos only, and the couple that say YouTube videos don't seem to work.
I've tried all the packages I could find (I'm not by my computer so can't look them up) and I've tried integrating the jQuery with my react app but I'm not expert enough to do that and understand the pros and cons.
Am I missing something obvious? Does anyone have a solution?
